# Consuming a C++ class reference from an external "plugin" library that doesn't have access to the class implementation

Tags: c++, plugins, linker, shared-libraries

I'm using the [Boost.DLL](http://apolukhin.github.io/Boost.DLL/) library for my project in order to offload its functionality into a suite of pluggable modules. The core application provides headers defining various structs and classes that will be used both within the core application, and which will (in some cases) be passed to plugins when they need to perform various tasks.

One of the initial things I need to do is pass a class `ServiceCatalog` to each plugin's initialization method, to allow that plugin to register various capabilities with the core application. I've grouped the definitions I'd like to share with my plugins into a header called `core.h`, and I'm referencing this header both in more application and in my plugin projects.

`ServiceCatalog` has a number of larger functions that, to me, make sense to offload into a cpp file, rather than trying to bundle them all into the header file. I'd still like the plugin to know the "shape" of the class though, because, while I don't need it to instantiate the class, I need it to be able to call instance methods.

However because I'm referencing the header file in the plugin, but not the cpp file containing the implementation, I get "unresolved external symbol" errors when linking. This makes sense on a basic level of course (i.e. what would happen if the plugin tried to instantiate something it doesn't have access to the implementation for?) but there doesn't seem to be any way (that I can find) to declare that the class is, I guess, "extern" or something?

Do I literally need to use a base abstract class to achieve this? Such a solution feels a little convoluted. I guess I could replace my class with a struct containing some function pointers instead.

What approach do you recommend? In a nutshell, I want my core application to be able to pass instances of things to my plugins, where each thing has a number of related methods that can be called.

```
// core.h, "main.exe"
class ServiceCatalog
{
public:
  void complex_method_with_external_implementation();
}

//plugin.cpp, "plugin.dll"
#include "core.h"
void register_plugin(ServiceCatalog* catalog)
{
  catalog->complex_method_with_external_implementation();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows, due to the exe and dll extensions. You probably need to look into the `__declspec` options for `dllexport` and `dllimport`.

Comment: @gigaplex I'm using the Boost.DLL library - it abstracts away these things and makes them work cross-platform.

Comment: I thought you were asking about how to make your class in your plugin work across a DLL boundary. I'd expect you to need to use dllexport and dllimport (via macros depending on whether you're building your plugin or including it elsewhere) on your ServiceCatalog class definition.

Comment: @gigaplex See the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, the `ServiceCatalog` object is only created by the "main.exe" program, and not in any of the plugins.  If that's the case, you can declare the functions that can be called by the plugins as `virtual`.

```
class ServiceCatalog
{
public:
  virtual void complex_method_with_external_implementation();
}
```

Then all of the reference to them will be in the vtable, referenced by the constructor.  The plugins will access the functions thru the vtable so they don't need any sort of export.

There are issues with versioning, as adding new 'exports' needs to be done in such a way not to mess up the existing layout of the vtable (you need to add them after all existing virtual functions, not insert them in between two existing virtual functions), and you can't remove any, either, without replacing them with something else.

Comment: Excellent, that did it, thanks! Regarding versioning; in this context I'm not worrying about that right now. The types of versioning conflicts I'd expect would require plugin upgrades anyway.

Comment: At the very least, make sure the interface to query the version is build in a conflict free manner, so the code can safely bail if the wrong version is detected. Then you can refactor the rest of the interfaces as you please.